# I have a problem with a very easy program in python with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm trying this simple code using Python and tkinter. Every time that I start the program the tkinter window pop-up correctly and if I press "Play" the cycle start. But after that, if I want to stop the process with the "Stop" button the program is not responding. I think that I should use multi process or multi thread because when the cycle start, the interface is not working.

I am at the beginning of Python so please be understanding with me :D

I have searched something on google but all the things that I found are too complicated, can someone explain how to do in an easy way?

```
from pynput.keyboard import  Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
import time
import random
import string
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")
window.title("Test")
window.resizable(False,False)

def arresta_programma():
    avvia_programma.destroy()

def avvia_programma():
    r = 0 
    n = 0
    l = 0
    d = 0  
    while n < 1000 : 
        keyboard= KeyboardController()
        keyboard.press('1')
        keyboard.release('1')
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
        keyboard.press('1')
        keyboard.release('1')

        r = random.randint(1,4)

        if r == 1 and l <= 2:
            keyboard= KeyboardController()
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
            keyboard.press(Key.left)
            time.sleep(random.randint(0,1))
            keyboard.release(Key.left)
            n = n + 1
            l = l + 1
            d = d - 1

first_button = tk.Button(text = "Play" , command = avvia_programma)
first_button.grid(row = 5, column = 5)

first_button = tk.Button(text = "Stop" , command = arresta_programma)
first_button.grid(row = 6, column = 6)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window.mainloop()
```

I would like the program responding even after the user push the "play" button. I would also like the "stop" button to make the interface open and ready to press "Play" again.

Comment: Please indent your code using 4-spaces tabs and try to avoid mant blank lines as this makes the post less readable

Comment: Isn't the code 4-space away? Sorry but I am new.

Comment: Can you try removing the parts of the program that aren't related to your question?

Comment: I shortened the program hoping to make it more understandable

Comment: you could use `window.after(time, callback)` instead of using `sleep()` and it will not freeze GUI but it would need more changes then using thread. You could also use `window.update()` in few places in your loop to update widgets and then GUI doesn't look like frozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you said, you should use at least threads. You cannot use time.sleep in your code, in your mainLoop which in this case tkinter handles. Tons of sleeps and loops blocks your loop and it crashes.

I would suggest to create class which inherits from threading.Thread. Example for "play" below.

```
from threading import Thread
def execute_avvia():
    job = AvviaProgramma()
    job.setDaemon(True)
    job.start()

class AvviaProgramma(Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AvviaProgramma, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.n = 0
        self.r = 0
        self.l = 0
        self.d = 0

    def run(self):
        while self.n < 1000:
            print(self.n)
            keyboard = KeyboardController()
            keyboard.press('1')
            keyboard.release('1')
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
            keyboard.press('1')
            keyboard.release('1')

            r = random.randint(1, 4)

            if r == 1 and self.l <= 2:
                keyboard = KeyboardController()
                time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
                keyboard.press(Key.left)
                time.sleep(random.randint(0, 1))
                keyboard.release(Key.left)
                self.n = self.n + 1
                self.l = self.l + 1
                self.d = self.d - 1


first_button = tk.Button(text = "Play", command=execute_avvia)
first_button.grid(row = 5, column = 5)
```

as you can see, I closed your while loop inside class method's run(), which is taken from Thread. This solution is not perfect, but I hope enough clear for beginner.

Good luck!